# Django querying an inherited model

Tags: django-models

I have something similar to the example below

```
from django.db import models    
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class a(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class b(a):
   value = models.IntegerField()

class c(a):
   model_id = models.IntegerField()
```

I have a User instance assigned to variable `current_user`, is there any way I can make `current_user.b_set` work? Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1):

The FK is on `a`, not `b`, so there is no "b_set". You can query `User` for objects that have an `a` that have a `b`, but `a_set` is the only property you have.

Comment: What would be a good way to query the `a_set` for all the `b` s?

Comment: I *think* it's `.filter(a__b__isnull=False)`, but I'm not certain. I gave up on model inheritance a while back.